# Why does input type number doesn't accept value '+'?

Tags: html, forms, input

I am creating a form in HTML for Sign Up into my website. In this form, there will be a input element in which users  will have to enter their mobile number, but with country code. As I live in India, country code will be **+91**. And for the convenience of user not to enter country code, I have added value +91 to this input element.

```
<input type="number" value="+91" name="mobileNumber">
```

But, this value doesn't appear in the input element after the webpage loads. And when I remove '+' from the value property, then the value (91) appears. But country code must include '+'. So, my question is why value property doesn't accept Plus sign? Is there any way to include it in value?

Comment: What makes you think that `+` is a number?

Comment: Because + is not a number, and +91 equals 91. So the plus sign is not accepted ( the minus ( - ) sign is accepted though. Why not use type="text"? and validate the input in PHP with regular expressions?

Comment: [`<input type="tel">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel) might suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks lvar, input type tel solved my problem

Comment: Because input type number doesn't accept '+' in value property, but when I type '+' when on a webpage, it accepts it!  @Nico Haase